# git ignore everything except files in certain subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

I just created a folder like this:

```
.
├── config
│   ├── subfolder
│   │   └── config.xml
│   └── subfolder2
│       └── config.xml
├── .gitignore
├── log2.txt
└── log.txt
```

And I've typed `git init` in this folder. I want to ignore everything except `.gitignore`, and all `config.xml` files.

These are the `.gitignore` I have tried:

1:

```
*
!.gitignore
!**/config.xml
```

2:

```
*
!.gitignore
!config/*/config.xml
```

3:

```
*
!.gitignore
!**/config.xml
```

`git status` shows `.gitignore` is the only untracked file with any one of the gitignore settings above.

I want all the `config.xml` files to be on the untracked files list too.

I've read the tutorial at [atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore). And I think that maybe it's the following rule that makes me not able to ignore everything except certain files under subdirectories.

I'm using `git version 2.11.0.windows.1` in windows 10 operating system. Anyone knows why my `.gitignore` file is not working the way I expect?

[image]

Comment: Could you create a github repo without the gitignore so it's easier to simulate what you want?

Comment: https://github.com/lyenliang/TestGitignore

Comment: Hi, I just pushed the folder to github so that it's easier for everyone to simulate.

Comment: That image you pasted (with the "Nope! Due to a ... quirk") is the key. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37507408/1256452

Comment: But how do you explain lapinkoira's `.gitignore` works for him, but not for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to torek's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507029/git-ignore-how-do-you-override-an-exception-to-an-ignore-all/37507408#37507408), I finally come up with the following solution:

```
/**
!/**/
!.gitignore
!**/config.xml
```

Comment: You don't need all these double asterisks. The following should have the same outcome, at least it works for me with your example repo (although I'm on MacOS and not Windows). Empty spaces stand for newlines since I cannot insert a line break in the comments:
`/* !/*/ !.gitignore !config.xml`

Comment: @gucce you are right. `/* !/*/ !.gitignore !config.xml` works on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Cloned your repo.

With this .gitignore:

```
*
!.gitignore
!*/*/config.xml
```

It's ignoring everything but .gitignore and config files:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   config/subfolder/config.xml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
.
├── config
│   ├── subfolder
│   │   ├── config.xml
│   │   └── ignoringthis
│   └── subfolder2
│       └── config.xml
├── log3.txt
└── newdir
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: This `.gitignore` doesn't work on my computer. Are you also using windows operating system?

Comment: I don't see `modified:   config/subfolder/config.xml` line on my computer

Comment: Ahh windows, can you try with !*\\*\\config.xml ?